# jqGrid colmodel.name != json key

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jqgrid

i am not good at english(ㅠㅠ)

jqgrid code

```
colModel : [{
                name:'top_code', align:'center', hidden:true, 
            }, {
                name:'top_code_name', align:'center',
            }, {
                name:'mid_code', align:'center', hidden:true, 
            }, {
                name:'mid_code_name', align:'center',
            }, {
                name:'code', align:'center',
            }, {
                name:'code_name', align:'center',
            }],
```

---

Vo

```
private String seq;
private String code; 
private String code_name; 
private String code_gb; 
private String bigo;
private String print_seq;

private String m_cseq;
private String m_code; 
private String m_code_name; 
private String m_code_gb; 
private String m_print_seq;

private String code_depth;
```

---

i want

if (depth.value)
json.key ->  colmodel.name

▼▼▼▼▼▼

```
  if(code_depth==1){
  code = top_code;
  code_name = top_code_name;
}else if(code_depth==2){
  m_code = mid_code;
  m_code_name = mi_code_name;
}else if(code_depth==3){
 code = code;..
 code_name = code_name;}
```

Where do I enter the code ?
What should I do?

i don't want dynamic binding
static colmodel !!

Comment: json data is List<Vo> to jsong by jackson...?

Comment: what is your problem actually

Comment: json key != colmodel.name ->different but '
Depending on the depth you want to give the value' google  Translation

Comment: Depending on the depth value
I want to put one of the key values of the json colmodel.

Comment: {
                name:top_code, align:'center', hidden:true, 
            }, have you tried the top_code with no quotes.